# unmounting USB CM12?

Tags: cyanogenmod, usb, usb-on-the-go

I'm using CM12 on a rooted Nexus 7 2012 (grouper). When I plug in my USB through OTG cable, I can access it using the default file manager, but an "umount USB" option is nowhere to ne seen!
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Open "storage" (or "memory") in settings, and on the list there will be USB storage and the option to unmount it

Comment: there is no list, just the usage of my internal storage

Comment: http://imgur.com/isiEY7A

Comment: Is this with USB storage connected? It doesn't show up in that place, under internal storage?

Comment: No. Only in file manager under "storage/usb" path

Comment: http://imgur.com/LQYn2gw

Comment: And everytime I disconnect it, I get warned that I didn't securely eject it